# Squirrel: How to print without e^?

Tags: squirrel

```
local MAX = 0.059513641346164345134111361369;
print( MAX );
```

**Output:** `0.661467`

```
local MAX = 0.000000000000000000000000000001;
print( MAX );
```

**Output:** `1e-030`

I want to display the entire 30 digits after the decimal point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use squirrel's [format()](http://www.squirrel-lang.org/squirreldoc/stdlib/stdstringlib.html#format) function, it behaves like printf in C

```
local MAX = 0.059513641346164345134111361369;
print(format("%.30f", MAX));

local MAX = 0.000000000000000000000000000001;
print(format("%.30f", MAX));
```

You must specify how many digits to print after the comma (in this case 30)